# How is Python's sys.getdefaultencoding() used?

Tags: python, character-encoding

Python's default encoding got me confused.

There is an á character in a text file's content.
The file is saved as UTF-8 in notepad.
When I don't specify encoding='utf-8' in:

```
with open(filename,encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

it shows up as Ã¡.
When I do add the encoding='utf-8' part it shows up as á.

I am wondering what sys.getdefaultencoding() is useful for, as this shows utf-8, but I still had to specify utf-8 as encoding for the á to show up in the output.

I'm using Python3.

Extra edit:

The encoding that is used is probably latin-1 extended I think. Since:
á in utf-8 maps to 0xC3 0xA1 and in latin-1 extended: 0xC3 maps to Ã 0xA1 maps to ¡

How could I verify that latin-1 extended will be used when not specifying encoding?

Comment: Per documentation, the default used by [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`, not `sys.getdefaultencoding()`.  The latter is the default for `str.encode()` or `bytes.decode()`.

Comment: Note: the problem is not on open, but on `print`. Python thinks you are using a Latin1 console, so it set default encoding as Latin1, and so it uses it to print, Note: it is just Windows which doesn't use UTF-8 as default (but it was one of the first operating system to use Unicode **internally**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the docs in [Built-in Functions -> open()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open):

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
```

> …
>  In text mode, if *encoding* is not specified the encoding used
> is platform dependent: [`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) is
> called to get the current locale encoding.
> …

where [`locale.getpreferredencoding(do_setlocale=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding)

> Return the encoding used for text data, according to user preferences.

[`sys.getdefaultencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.getdefaultencoding) is different (and *independent*):

> Return the name of the current default string encoding used by the
> Unicode implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that explains it.